# ejs forEach function not working for json data in node

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

forEach is not a function when I am iterating json file in ejs using nodejs giving some error while iterating.. below is three section what i have done in .ejs file, json and nodeJS

1. Here is my JSON Data

   ```
          <pre> 
           {
               "MenuName": "Main Menu Here",
               "widget": {
                   "window": {
                       "data": "Click Here",
                       "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
                       "name": "main_window",
                       "width": 500,
                       "height": 500
                   },
                   "window": {
                       "data": "Click Here",
                       "src": "Images/Sun.png",
                       "name": "sun1",
                       "hOffset": 250,
                       "vOffset": 250,
                       "alignment": "center"
                   },
                   "window": {
                       "data": "Click Here",
                       "size": 36,
                       "style": "bold",
                       "name": "text1",
                       "hOffset": 250,
                       "vOffset": 100,
                       "alignment": "center",
                       "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
                   }
               }
           }
           </pre>
   ```
2. This is my ejs

   ```
           <html>
           <head>
           <title><%= title %></title>
           </head>
           <body>
               <h1> My Name Is <%= title %></h1>
               <h1> My Name Is <%= printIt.MenuName %></h1>
               <ul>
                   <% printIt.widget.forEach(function(item){%> 
                       <li><%= item.window.data%></li>
                   <% }); %>
               </ul>
           </body> 

           </html>
           </pre>
   ```
3. in NodeJS

   ```
   <pre>
       app.locals.printIt = require("./sample.json");
   </pre>

       I can able to print 
       My Name Is <%= title %> and My Name Is <%= printIt.MenuName %>

       What i missed here..?
   ```

Comment: I can able to print <%= title%> and <%= printIt.MenuName %> but unable to iterating window key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON data will keep only single record of widget window and which is last one. Because window key will overwrite previous hold value.

Update your script with this one

```
<ul>
  <% for(var item in printIt.widget){%> 
    <li><%= printIt.widget[item].data%></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

*Hope this will help to solve your query !!*

Comment: i shouldn't change the json data and I want all "data" key values in <li>

Comment: @Naresh, just update your script with this then see result

Comment: Still I am getting error with above script even if i changed my JSON file to single record. and I have made change in my code like this I am getting single record of "data" key. but i want all key value

Comment: code changed like this <% for(var item in printIt.widget){ %>
   <li><%= printIt.widget[item]["data"] %></li>
  <% } %>

Comment: If i am writing this code <% for(var item in printIt.widget){ %> <li><%= printIt.widget[item]["data"] %></li> <% } %> i am not getting any error and i am getting last window.data key value. but i want each window data key value.

Comment: I've told earlier - "your JSON data will keep only single record of widget window and which is last one". To see this, can you `console.log(printIt);` in your app.js before render view?

Comment: That is fine. but my question is there any ways to get each window data key value..?

Comment: You have to make window key unique in your `printIt.widget` by adding some other literal element like this - `window1`, `window2`, and etc.

Comment: @Naresh, If this answer has solved your issue then accept it.